# Differentiation help with two variables

Tags: derivatives

Say if we had the function
$y= ln(a) x$ how would we find $dy/dx$?
Do we take other variables to be constant, if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ is related to $x$ then use the chain rule and product rule.

$\frac {d}{dx} (x\ln a) = \ln a + \frac {x}{a}\frac {da}{dx}$

If there is no relation between $a$ and $x$ you can treat $a$ as if it were a constant.  Equivalently, you could say that $\frac {da}{dx} = 0$

Comment: By saying "as if it were" are you saying a is a variable but IT'S value doesn't change hence it hving the same properties as a constant